# CSS3 radial background, is there a cheat for it?

Tags: css

```
            background: #008080; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #008080 0%, #0896a5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#008080), color-stop(100%,#0896a5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #008080 0%,#0896a5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #008080 0%,#0896a5 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
            background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #008080 0%,#0896a5 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #008080 0%,#0896a5 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#008080', endColorstr='#0896a5',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

I want this as background for my webpage but that doesn't seem to work untill i add 100% width and height to `*` like so: `* { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` but that will mess up the rest of my page. So is there a cheat for it to still obtain this effect?

Comment: Works for me. What's the problem?

Comment: I want it to be a fixed background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `background-attachment` to `fixed`:

```
background: radial-gradient(cover, #008080 0%, #0896a5 100%) fixed;
```